Is a soul totally in darkness with no ability to come to Christ or is there a chink of light that falls on all souls .. that is creation
For Calvinism to be true .. not one chink of light can get into a soul .. but on the other hand the Bible says there is a chink of light that does get through ( that is the wonder of God’s creation ) :-


See https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/87357/god-our-savior-who-desires-all-people-to-be-saved-is-the-greek-clear-on-wheth/87367#87367  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/54547/does-god-want-everyone-to-be-saved-or-not/54548#54548  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/96412/what-factors-need-to-be-taken-into-account-in-assessing-the-meaning-of-the-will/96423#96423

see also  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/88310/how-did-the-early-church-who-spoke-greek-understand-1-timothy-21-6-did-they/88313#88313  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/74752/does-god-deliberately-choose-people-to-be-christians-in-1-cor-126-29/74759#74759   https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/71736/what-does-election-of-grace-mean-in-romans-115/71740#71740  etc.

Please enter real text, not images. Images are generally not indexed by search engines and people with poor vision that rely on voice browsers will have no idea what this question is about unless you give the image a very good description in its <alt> tag.  In this case the description you supplied is "enter image description here".

This question is similar to: Is Calvinism true?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The question is different in that it doesn’t mention Calvinism in the actual question . So it is a Biblical question about Romans 1v20 ..  the question  alludes to Romans 1v20 and asks if 1v20 means all people receive light about God .

Everyone has been given the ability to come to the light, but not everyone wants to.  Your verse (and that chapter) definitely state that as truth.

It is better to avoid 'isms' on this site and to refer to scripture itself. If you mean 'election' then that is Pauline doctrine.

Thanks .. I’m finding it difficult to keep editing the question .. basically there are those who talk of total depravity giving spiritual blindness .. but the Bible says in Romans 1v20 that God is clearly seen by all ( because of His creation ) . So can someone harmonise these two statements .. what I’m saying isn’t that hard to understand .. can’t someone attempt an answer ?

Thanks Mark Vestal .. sorry I hadn’t seen your answer .. I thank you for it .

"The question is different in that it doesn’t mention Calvinism in the actual question" — It certainly does mention Calvinism; it very explicitly begins with: "For Calvinism to be true .. not one chink of light can". ¶ And where does this "chink of light" expression come from?

The word Calvinism is in the further explanation to the question  ( but not the question itself ) .. the Calvinist talks of Total Depravity causing spiritual blindness .. but Romans 1v20 speaks of light being seen , ‘His eternal power ‘ etc .. leading me to say some light is coming thro .. which I refer to as a chink of light ..

The physical eye may see the splendour of the heavens, and the soul is culpable if it does not properly appreciate that significance. Nevertheless, the natural man receiveth not the things of God. . . . . . . We must be born again. And that requires the initiative of a Father. (There is no contradiction.)  Up-voted +1.

But the verse ( Rom 1v20 ) says the natural man of himself can see His eternal power .. the Calvinist would say the natural man sees  it but it doesn’t means anything to him .. but the Bible says it does mean something to him .. so much so that the natural man is ‘without excuse’ if  he doesn’t go on to seek God further …

So creation means something to man .. and he is culpable if he doesn’t respond properly .. but the Calvinist says initially nothing means anything to man .. wherein lies the contradiction between the Calvinist and Romans 1v20 ..

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE Mark. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out educating new users and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality questions and answers. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

The physical eye may see the splendour of the heavens, and the soul is culpable if it does not properly appreciate that significance.
Nevertheless, the natural man receiveth not the things of God, 1 Corinthians 2:14.
We must be born again, John 3:3 and 3:7.
And that requires the initiative of a Father.
There is no contradiction.
For 'in thy light shall we see light' Psalm 36:9.
If we do not receive His light, then we abide in darkness.

All references are to the KJV/Received Text.

So creation means something to man .. and he is culpable if he doesn’t respond properly .. but the Calvinist says initially nothing means anything to man .. wherein lies the contradiction between the Calvinist and Romans 1v20 .. –
mark danks
Commented 1 min ago


Can you substantiate the statement 'the Calvinist says . . . .  etc'. Which Calvinist ? 2.  I have not quoted Calvin. I have quoted John and Paul and David. 3. There is no contradiction between election (see Paul, not Calvin) and regeneration.

